# Installed R package not found in library folder

Tags: r, windows, brms

I try to install whatever package as follows in R (regardless if it is R 4.0 or R 4.2):

```
install.packages("brms")
```

and this

```
install.packages("brms", lib = "path/win-library")
```

I get this:

```
* installing *source* package 'brms' ...
** package 'brms' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
Warning: namespace 'brms' is not available and has been replaced
by .GlobalEnv when processing object 'brmsfit_example1'
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  there is no package called 'shiny'
Calls: <Anonymous> ... loadNamespace -> withRestarts -> withOneRestart -> doWithOneRestart
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'brms'
* removing 'C:/Users/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/brms'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘brms’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp0IDKze\downloaded_packages’
```

But, when I then want to load it into R it does not exist and I get an error:

```
library(brms)
Error in library(brms) : there is no package called ‘brms’
```

I do not even see the folders containing `brms` in either of the `.libPaths()`. I have tried to unzip the downloaded folder `brms` in the temporary folder to the `libPaths`, but that does not work either.

I have searched the internet but have not found a proper solution.
What should I do to change it? All my packages do not work.

Comment: Your package is not installed, you probably missed error messages during installation.

Comment: I get an error that the `shiny` package cannot be called, and the lazy loading fails. See edit, please.

Comment: I guess something gets loaded in RStudio during startup. Try to uncheck _Tools > Global options > Workspace > Restore .RData_ and set _Save workspace_ to never. You can also try to install brms w/o RStudio in the console; open a cmd and type `R.exe`, R should open, then just `install.packages('brms')` and see what happens.

Comment: When you are doing the installation step, look at `print(.libPaths())` and note the first directory. It is the default target. Check (via `cmd.exe` or Windows Explorer) that it was indeed written -- it very likely was.  Next, when you fire up R check `print(.libPaths())` again.  It may now be different because you may have two different configuration settings.  You need to straighten set that.  I often recommend to use an explicit library path (say: `C:/opt/R/library`) that also persists when you update R.